# Modify materialize "fixed-action-btn click-to-toggle" to 'collapse' again once selection is clicked

Tags: javascript, materialize, floating-action-button

I am using materialize `fixed-action-btn vertical click-to-toggle`and its working like it should: one click opens the menu options and another click on menu closes them again.

HOWEVER i need the menu-options that become available after the main 'Menu' button is clicked to go away again/'collapse' once ANY one of them has been clicked, not the main menu button. i.e. i dont want the user to have to separately re-click the menu again to hide the menu-items.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/css/materialize.min.css">}

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>                   

    <div class="fixed-action-btn vertical click-to-toggle" style="bottom: 44px; right: 24px;">
    <a class="btn-floating btn-large orange lighten -3"> <i class="material-icons">menu</i>   </a>
    
    <ul>
      <li><button class="btn-floating green darken-2" onclick="displayV(1)">opt1</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-floating green lighten-1"onclick="displayV(2)">opt2</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-floating red lighten-1" onclick="displayV(3)">opt3</button></li>
      <li><button class="btn-floating red darken-3" onclick="displayV(4)">opt4</button></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

How can i tweak this FAB button type?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is too late, but I hope it is still help others to solve this kind of problem.

1. Just add the main the main button with an id

```html
<a id="main-btn" class="btn-floating btn-large red">
```

2. Write this event handler to all li elements inside the .fixed-action-btn

```js
$(".fixed-action-btn li").on('click', function() {
  $("#main-btn").click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.click-to-toggle').on('click', function(e) {
    var current = e.currentTarget;
    // looping on every opened menu (.active)
    $('.click-to-toggle.active').filter(function() {
        // close it if it's not the clicked menu (with materialize's closeFAB())
        return !(this === current);
    }).closeFAB();
})
```